# VS Code - running debug in 2021 (VS Code 1.60.0 (user setup)) doesn't respond

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have an app I built in 2020 and now I have updated all libraries, Visual Studio Code, npm, ng etc.  But now I don't know how to debug in MS Code!

Have dropped the old *Debugger for Chrome extension*, and I generated an "Attach to Chrome" and a "Launch Chrome", and my impression is that I needed to `Launch` then `Attach` clicking on the green arrow with `ng serve` and it starts the node server

`This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular ...`

It rebuilds everything and ends with
`√ Compiled successfully.`
The app **is** up in the browser.
Debug toolbar is shown in the IDE.

Call stack (LHS) shows
(BugIcon) ng serve:localhost:4200/# running
A break point is set in a method of a component which is on the screen, but the breakpoint was NOT hit and the breakpoint stays unbound.

**Now, I'm not sure what the I am supposed to click on to debug**
`Run menu | Start Debugging` seems likely.
Nope, that says 'It looks like a browser is already running from the old debug session.  Please close

Maybe switching the RUN AND DEBUG dropdown to `Attach to Chrome` and clicking the Green Button gets a
`(BugIcon) Attach to Chrome in the Call Stack`
but that eventually goes away.  I see no errors.

**Is something wrong with my configurations/launches etc.?**
Any ideas?
Is port 9222 in the Attach to Chrome correct?

So much for automatically generated json file. :(
Here is my `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        
        {
            "name": "ng serve",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/*": "*",
                "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
            }
        },
...
```

***EDIT: At least I found a solution which works; see below.***

Comment: Check my previous answer on that topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516582/7237884

Comment: You can't say what the right sequence is to even try debugging.  I was really look for an answer to the question of what is supposed to be the right sequence of clicks or commands.

You say to not use the debugger in VS Code, but use the tools in the browser, but you don't say how to do that.  

I start the app, then the dev tools in the Chrome browser and I don't see original ts sources, so that solution is not working.  

Do I need a VS Code extension or config setting for debugging using the browser tools?

Comment: Original. Ts files should be inside webpack folder and then under `. ` folder. Then you click on the left side of the line to place a blue breakpoint to debug a specific line

Comment: Apparently, you mean in the browser which in my case is Chrome AND in Chromes menu | more tools | Dev tools (or Ctrl Shift I) in sources tab

and then . folder?  What?
 I see is 
Top
> localhost:4200 
  > Assets (my applications) pngs, jpegs directly from the project src/assets 
  and apparently my ts source translated to js.
 main.js
polyfill.js
runtime.js
styles.js 
styles.css

Sorry no . directory.
SO yup the sources aren't sent over for debugging.
I have no idea if under the new debugging method they would be and my configuration is screwed.

Comment: try again starting it with `ng serve  --optimization=false --sourceMap=true` and check again

Comment: If you have an answer, please use the Your Answer box and post it as an answer. Please do not edit your question and add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown and restart VS Code

Use the command as suggested by Panagiotis Bougioukos above.

```
> ng serve --optimization=false --sourceMap=true 
Option "optimization" is deprecated: Use the "optimization" option in the browser builder instead. 
Option "sourceMap" is deprecated: Use the "sourceMap" option in the browser builder instead.
```

Ignore the warnings and then use the
RUN DEBUG command (as originally generated, see original question) from the drop down and hit the green arrow.
`Launch Chrome`

***At least, I can debug in the IDE and the browser!!!!***

The *error/warning* message hints to me I have some tools mismatch within the whole compile, build and deploy tool chain, but I don't know which, nor do I know how to work out what is mismatched.